# Find latest/published version of post using wp-cli

Tags: wp-cli

```
wp --ssh=barrycar@bc4 --path=public_html/wordpress --fields=ID,post_title,post_name,post_date,post_status,post_author,post_parent,post_type,filter,guid,menu_order,post_content --format=yaml post list
```

I used the command above to download all posts on my WordPress blog. I'd like to know which version of a given post is live on the site. Relevant portion of YAML output:

```
-
  ID: 22371
  post_title: Albuquerque Street Names
  post_name: 13019-revision-4
  post_date: 2012-03-06 03:00:53
  post_status: inherit
  post_author: 2
  post_parent: 13019
  post_type: post
  filter: raw
  guid: http://wordpress.barrycarter.org/index.php/2012/03/06/13019-revision-4/
  menu_order: 0
  post_content: [...]
-
  ID: 22370
  post_title: Albuquerque Street Names
  post_name: 13019-revision-4
  post_date: 2011-11-24 16:47:32
  post_status: inherit
  post_author: 2
  post_parent: 13019
  post_type: post
  filter: raw
  guid: http://wordpress.barrycarter.org/index.php/2011/11/24/13019-revision-4/
  menu_order: 0
  post_content: [...]
- 
  ID: 13019
  post_title: Albuquerque Street Names
  post_name: albuquerque-street-names
  post_date: 2011-09-03 03:38:21
  post_status: publish
  post_author: 2
  post_parent: 0
  post_type: post
  filter: raw
  guid: http://wordpress.barrycarter.org/?p=13019
  menu_order: 0
  post_content: [...]
```

If I had to guess, I'd say ID 22371 is the version that's live on the site, because:

- It has the highest ID of the three
- It ties for highest "revision" (revision-4) of the three
- It has the latest post_date of the three

However, this seems indirect. What's the correct way of finding which is the currently published version? Related questions:

- What filter gives me only live current posts? `--post-status=publish` seems like it'll give me the first version of each post.
- Why are there two 13019-revision-4 and no 13019-revision-3 or 13019-revision-2 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, the current revision has these properties as compared to revisions:

- The post_status will be "publish" not "inherit".
- The post_parent will be 0
- The post_type will be "post" not "revision".

Additionally, the ID of the current revision doesn't change when you update the post; instead, the older version is given a new ID.

Example:

- I created a post called "test post" with content "this is revision one.". It was assigned ID 28623. When I did "wp post get 28623", the interesting part of the output was:

```
ID      28623
post_date       2017-12-13 16:26:02
post_content    this is revision one.
post_title      test post
post_status     publish
comment_status  open
ping_status     open
post_name       test-post
post_modified   2017-12-13 16:26:02
post_parent     0
post_type       post
```

- I then edited the content to read "this is revision two" and did "wp post get 28623" again. The results this time:

```
ID      28623
post_date       2017-12-13 16:26:02
post_content    this is revision two.
post_title      test post
post_status     publish
comment_status  open
ping_status     open
post_name       test-post
post_modified   2017-12-13 16:28:47
post_parent     0
post_type       post
```

Notice that post id 28623 itself has changed fields, and the live version if still id 28623. The post_date remains the same but the post_modified has changed.

What happened to the old version? I did "wp post get 28624". The results:

```
ID      28624
post_date       2017-12-13 16:26:02
post_content    this is revision one.
post_title      test post
post_status     inherit
comment_status  closed
ping_status     closed
post_name       28623-revision-v1
post_modified   2017-12-13 16:26:02
post_parent     28623
post_type       revision
```

The old version has been copied to a new row in the database. Note that there's no guarantee that the revision will have the ID immediately following the original post's id: wordpress will just use the next available id (it worked in my case because I didn't make any posts between the post and its revision).

- Additionally:

  - the post_status is now "inherit", not "publish"
  - the post_type is "revision" not "post"
  - the post_parent is 28623, not 0
  - the post_name has changed to "28623-revision-v1" instead of "test-post", and no longer references the title. If the original post is at "(something)/test-post", you might be tempted to visit "(something)/28623-revision-v1" to see the revision. However, WordPress will yield a "page not found" error, since it doesn't allow end users to see revisions.
  - the post_modified is still equal to the post_date, since this was the original version
  - the "comment_status" and "ping_status" are now closed, since it wouldn't make sense to comment on or ping a revision. Of course, live posts can also have these both be "closed", but, if you allow comments/pings on a post, that permission will automatically be removed for older revisions.
- I then reverted back to the original version, and did "wp post get 28623" to get:

```
ID      28623
post_author     1
post_date       2017-12-13 16:26:02
post_content    this is revision one.
post_title      test post
post_status     publish
comment_status  open
ping_status     open
post_name       test-post
post_modified   2017-12-13 16:46:20
post_type       post
```

Notice that the post has now returned to the original version, with one exception: the post_modified date no longer matches the post_date. In other words, if you modify a post and then modify it back, that's considered two modifications, not an undo of a modification (you can see this in the admin interface by noticing the "revisions" count is now 3, not 1 or 2).

Another way to see this is to do "wp post get 28624":

```
ID      28624
post_date       2017-12-13 16:26:02
post_content    this is revision one.
post_title      test post
post_status     inherit
comment_status  closed
ping_status     closed
post_name       28623-revision-v1
post_modified   2017-12-13 16:26:02
post_parent     28623
post_type       revision
```

Notice that, even though we've reverted to version 1, a separate copy of version 1 exists as a revision. Version 2 was given a new id as we see by doing "wp post get 28625".

```
ID      28625
post_date       2017-12-13 16:28:47
post_content    this is revision two.
post_title      test post
post_status     inherit
comment_status  closed
ping_status     closed
post_name       28623-revision-v1
post_modified   2017-12-13 16:28:47
post_modified_gmt       2017-12-13 16:28:47
post_parent     28623
post_type       revision
```